# How to use a generated page from Gatsby as a homepage?

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I am having a page template, which creates multiple pages. One of them is my homepage and it has a slug "home". How can I set it to be the default page when I visit the site - example.com

Bonus: how to make it so when I visit example.com/home to redirect me to example.com

Comment: Looks like we are asking the very same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721965/the-right-way-to-define-a-sourced-page-as-gatsbys-front-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The right way to define a sourced page as Gatsby's front page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721965/the-right-way-to-define-a-sourced-page-as-gatsbys-front-page)

Comment: There is an official solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426759/10495311

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby integrates well with `@reach/router`. A Router redirect allows redirecting to any other route, no matter where it comes from. Apply it on `src/pages/index.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { Router, Redirect } from "@reach/router"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Router>
      <Redirect noThrow
        from="/"
        to="/whateverYourFrontpagesRouteIs"
      />
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>
)

export default IndexPage
```

This also a valid answer to your bonus question.