# The right way to define a sourced page as Gatsby's front page

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

I created a Gatsby/React instance sourcing from a Wordpress instance. I generate pages based on the page objects that I source from Wordpress. Everything works fine. I know that I have to put my content for the route `/` into `src/pages/index.js`. What would be the correct/canonical way to define one of my sourced page routes e.g.`/start` as `/`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just call `createPage` with the path set to `/`. How you handle this in your CMS really depends on the structure you've set.

```js
exports.createPages = ({ actions }) =>
  actions.createPage({
    path: "/",
    component: path.resolve("./src/templates/some_template.jsx"),
  })
```

I tend to prefer to require preceding and trailing slashes on slugs (e.g. `/about/`) in the CMS, which makes it easy to allow a content editor to leave just `/` for a page that is destined to become the home/root page. In the past I've also used `home` as a magic value that would be converted to `/` in `gatsby-node.js`, but it can cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you, does that mean that I have to delete `src/pages/index.js` in order to make this work?

Comment: @radscheit I can't recall; I believe so, though.